# Mixed PHP and HTML to pdf

Tags: php

I'm trying to use PhpToPdf libraries to export my page to pdf. However my page has mixed html and php outputs on it. This library requires to put all the markups in a   php variable as a string to export it. But in my case the output is okay on html parts while it outputs plain php codes in the php part.

Example code:

```
<?php
require("phpToPDF.php"); 

$my_html="<HTML>
<h2>Test HTML 01</h2><br><br>
<h2><?php echo "Test HTML 01";?></h2>
</HTML>";

$pdf_options = array(
"source_type" => 'html',
"source" => $my_html,
"action" => 'save',
"save_directory" => '',
"file_name" => 'html_01.pdf');

phptopdf($pdf_options);

// OPTIONAL - PUT A LINK TO DOWNLOAD THE PDF YOU JUST CREATED
echo ("<a href='html_01.pdf'>Download Your PDF</a>");
?>
```

Output on the pdf file:

### Test HTML 01

?php echo "Test HTML 01";?>

Is there any workaround to this problem?

Comment: can you try with single quotes `<?php echo 'Test HTML 01';?>`

Comment: @VasuKuncham Not working

Comment: _“while it outputs plain php codes in the php part”_ - well that’s because your “php part” isn’t actually a PHP part in the sense that it was actual _code_ - it is _data_ only, it is part of the content of a string variable. Instead of trying to assemble your output in a variable in this way, you should look into _output buffering_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already open PHP ...

```
 <?php
    $my_html="<HTML>
    <h2>Test HTML 01</h2><br><br>
    <h2><?php echo "Test HTML 01";?></h2>
    </HTML>";
```

Use:

```
$my_html="<HTML>
<h2>Test HTML 01</h2><br><br>
<h2>Test HTML 01</h2>
</HTML>";
```

or

```
$my_html="<HTML>
<h2>Test HTML 01</h2><br><br>
<h2>".$YourStrVariable."</h2>
</HTML>";
```